# Cascade Classifier Method

Tags: opencv, detect, cascade, face-detection, classification

I want to use the Cascade Classifier Method to compare a found round shape (from the image set where a face has been detected) and a reference circle that I define first so that I can match those two circles/ellipses: the one from the image, and the second which is used as a reference.

The goal is to say at the end, where the head is bigger or smaller from the reference.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

CascadeClassifier will return a vector of cv::Rect. If you're only trying to compare the relative size of the detection to the size of your reference you can probably just use the Rect and not worry about circles. You know the size of your reference, because you defined it, and then you compare that to the size of each detected Rect.

```
cv::Size referenceSize(24,24); //you know this before hand
cv::Rect detectedObject = detectedObjects[0];//look at first Rect from cascade
if(referenceSize.area() > detectedObject.area())
{ // detection is smaller than reference
}
else
{ // detection is larger than reference
}
```

You could also use the min/max size parameters of detectMultiScale to find objects that are only smaller or larger than your reference.